# No images L2A images available in GEE for whole January 2017 and 2018 for Southwest Ghana

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am not having any L2A S2 image for January,2017 and 2018  in GEE. 
Does anyone have an idea why I don't have S2_SR images over southwest Ghana?

My AOI is:

```
ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-1.360169990453731, 5.602184612970782, 0.282127959555828, 7.275599787296311)
```

The code is:

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.



var img2017 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-01-31')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
var img2018 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
var img2019 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31')
                 .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

print(img2017)
print(img2018)
print(img2019)
```

Comment: Turn off your cloud filtering and see if anything shows up.

Comment: Hi Jon, Tried it, Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the metadata for the COPERNICUS/S2_SR collection, it says

> The Sentinel-2 L2 data are downloaded from scihub. They were computed
>   by running sen2cor. WARNING: ESA did not produce L2 data for all L1
>   assets, and earlier L2 coverage is not global.

It appears that the scenes over your AOI are not available in the Level 2A collection. You can verify this by changing one (or all) of you imagecollections to `COPERNICUS/S2` instead of `COPERNICUS/S2_SR`. You will see that a number of `S2` scenes are available.